# Application Updater that also updates dependant files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, setup-deployment

Ok, so I've done a lot of research on this subject and I can't seem to find anything that really helps me, so I was hoping that the wealth of knowledge here can help.

**Background**

I have developed a C# .net application in Visual Studio 2012 that is going to be distributed to many computers around the country. The application is set up so that it looks at the .exe.config file for many settings. This is not an issue. What is an issue, is that there are also file directories, text and .dll files that my program also relies on.

**Questions**

So my question is this, is there a way to create a updater in C# to integrate with my application so that it not only updates the .exe if there is a new version, but also compares the version of the supporting files and updates them if necessary?

Also, is it possible to create an installer that will create these dependant directories and files without embedding them into the application itself?

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally approach this as follows:

- Have a webservice that reports the latest version
- Check the version (on startup?) and if there's a new one...
- Download a manifest listing all files/directories required by vNext, the url they can be downloaded from and some hash of the file (Sha1?)
- Compare the files and hashes you've downloaded to what's currently present on disk
- Generate a list of files which need to be updated to comply with the new manifest, and a list of files which are no longer required
- Download new files
- Delete obsolete files required by the previous manifest (so no legacy files kicking around being loaded by mistake). Make sure to avoid deleting user-created files!
- At a convenient time, restart your application

By using [Shadow copied assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx), you should be able to replace any files opened by the framework in-place without worrying about locks. You may need to handle files you've opened yourself differently (eg if you open a text file in code and it needs to be updated, you'll need to close the handle first)

Example webservice responses:

#### /LatestVersion

```
{"Version": {"Major": 1, "Minor": 0, "Revision": 0, "Build": 0},
 "Manifest": "/Version/1.0.0.0"}
```

#### /Version/1.0.0.0

```
{"Files": [{"/SomeDll.dll", "Hash": "AAAAAAAAAAAA", "Url": "/Version/1.0.0.0/SomeDll.dll"},
           {"/MainApp.exe", "Hash": "AAAAAAAAAAAB", "Url": "/Version/1.0.0.0/MainApp.exe"},
           ...
          ],
 "ReleaseNotes": "Blah"}
```

Of course, if each version of the app and supporting files is small, you may just want to download the manifest and associated files in one go ~(zip file?) rather than updating individual files piecemeal.

One other benefit of this approach is that you can theoretically roll forward/back to any version you like at any time (assuming there's no dependencies on a database schema/similar which changes over time).

### Make it secure!

You need to consider security when doing any automatic update process. You're effectively downloading new code and running it with the same permissions as your application (most likely, the same as the current user). At a bare minimum, **make sure you use SSL and that you validate the certificate you're presented with!** If you don't, anyone between the user and your server can substitute their own software. Familiarise yourself with how [Man in the Middle](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Understanding-Man-in-the-Middle-Attacks-ARP-Part1.html) attacks so you can defend against them.

Answer (score 0):

You could beta test Squirrel (a WiX wrapper):

https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows